# Margin-top not doing anything

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have looked at question similar to this but they haven't solved my problem :(
i have got a find out more button but it is overlapping text so i wanted to use margin-top to move the button but it doesn't do anything i have tried setting it to inline-block and everything along those lines
[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNCrO.png)

Code:

Html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Adams Vault</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th><h1 class="MainTitle">Adams Vault</h1><h1 class="SecondaryTitle">This Is My Imagination</h1></th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="navigation">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="news.asp">Apps</a></li>
                <li><a href="Games.html">Games</a></li>
                <li><a href="Music.html">Music</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.asp">Brain Storm</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.asp">Videos</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.asp">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content" style="height:3000;">
                <div style="background-color:white; width:100%; height: 500; border-radius: 15px;">
                <table style="">
                <tr>
                <td><h4 class="ThirdTitle">adamsvault.uphero.com</h4>
                <div class="slideshow-container">
                    <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <div class="numbertext"></div>
                    <img src="Images\P1.jpg" style="width:800; height: 400;">
                    <div class="text"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <div class="numbertext"></div>
                    <img src="Images\P2.png" style="width:800">
                    <div class="text"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <div class="numbertext"></div>
                    <img src="Images\P3.png" style="width:800">
                    <div class="text"></div>
                </div>
                </div></td>
                <br>
                <td style="vertical-align: top; margin-left:50;"><h1 style="padding-top:100px;">What Is This Website And Why?</h1>
                <br><p>I created this website to share everything i have designed created or even moddified over the years <br> another goal of this website is to express myself physically and mentally maybe sharing my taste of music <br>to even sharing the stuff i do as hobbys</td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
                <div style="background-color:white; margin-top: 50px; width:100%; height: 1500; border-radius: 15px; border: red solid 2px;">
                <center>
                <h1 style="text-decoration: red underline; font-size: 50px;"> News </h1>
                </center>
                <div class="storyb" >
                <center>
                <img src="Images\Story\WebLaunch.png" width="40%" height="60%" style="padding:5px;"><img src="Images\Story\WebLaunch.png" width="40%" height="60%" style="padding:5px;">
                <br><br><br><h1 style="color:white;" style="">Website Launch!</h1>
                <p>18/06/2017</p><p style="font-size:15px; color:white;"> Adams Vault has launched! from now on you will be able to use this amazing website</p>
                <p style="font-size:15px; color:white;">This website will allow you to view my work download my creations even modify my work (most of the stuff on this site will be open source)<br>If you are going to modify my projects please give credit to this website!</p>
                <a href="" class="find_out_more">Find Out More</a>
                </center>
                </span>
                </div>
                </div>
                <script>
                    var slideIndex = 0;
                    showSlides();

                    function showSlides() {
                    var i;
                    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                        slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
                    }
                    slideIndex++;
                    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
                        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
                    setTimeout(showSlides, 4000);
                }
                </script>

        </div>

        <div id="footer">

        Adams Vault 2017    

        </div>

    </body> 
</html>
```

CSS

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Walter+Turncoat);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Luckiest+Guy);

.ThirdTitle {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
    text-decoration: underline black; 
}

.MainTitle {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Walter Turncoat', cursive;
    text-decoration: underline black;
}

.SecondaryTitle {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;
    text-decoration: underline black; 
}
ul {
    top:110px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

}
li {
    float: left;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color: #DAC8BF;
}

.active {
    background-color: #ad7f69;
}

.active:hover {
    background-color: #ad7f69;
}
.textfeed {
    background-color:white;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
}

.head {
    background-color: #333;
}

*{ padding: 0; margin: 0; }

body {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;

}
#header {
 width: 100%;
 color: #333;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
 background: #DAC8BF;
}
#navigation {
 width: 100%;
 color: #333;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 background: #BD9C8C;
}
#content { 
 width: 100%;
 color: #333;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 background: #ffd9c6;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 height: 1350px;
}
#footer { 
 width: 100%;
 color: #333;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 background: #BD9C8C;
 margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
 padding: 10px;
}


* {box-sizing:border-box}

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

.mySlides {
    display: none;
}

.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

.download {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
}

.download:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: darkred;
}

.storyb {
    background-color:black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    border-top: 5px grey solid;
}

.storyw {
    background-color:black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35%;
}

.Down {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.find_out_more {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 5px 20px ;
    margin-top:
}

.find_out_more:hover; {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide us with jsfiddle. (https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Your example code does not contain the inline-block you said you tried, and an invalid declaration `margin-top:` without any actual value. Once both those silly mistakes are fixed, your issue seems to appear into non-existence ...

Comment: Thank you sorry i am silly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply margin top or bottom to an `inline` element, which is what an `a` tag is. You need to change it to `inline-block`. Below is the CSS you will need to add.

```
.find_out_more {
    display: inline-block;
    // Whatever margin top you want
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: For completeness, you can't  apply top and bottom margins to inline elements, but you can assign left and right margins.